# How to get the data attributes of a list of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given n html elements with `data` attributes such :

```
<div class="tpl" data-points="2"></div>
<div class="tpl" data-points="5"></div>
<div class="tpl" data-points="10"></div>
<div class="tpl" data-points="5"></div>
```

**How to get the value of these data-points into a single array ?**, so the final result is such as :

```
var historic = [ "2", "5", "10", "5"];
```

---

Edit: I eventually used :

```
$('.tpl').each(
  function (i) { 
       historic[i] = $(this).attr('data-points'); 
  }
);
```

Comment: +1 presented the question very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tpl').each(function(index){
        var data = $(this).attr('data-points');
        historic[index] = data;
        alert(data);
    });

});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvPH/5/)

Comment: Your code is the simpliest to understand. Thanks & +1

Comment: This is enough:  $('.tpl').each(function (i) {
    historic[i] = $(this).attr('data-points');
});

Comment: I was actually looking for this exact solution. I should have made some typo mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method with `.get` to retrieve the actual plain array of values:

```
var historic = $('.tpl').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('points');
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yuvPH/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var data = $('div.tpl').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('points');
}).get();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we3vq/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var historic=[ "0", "0", "0", "0"];
console.log("Initial: "+ JSON.stringify(historic));

i=0;
$(".tpl").each(function(){
   historic[i++]=$(this).attr('data-points');        
});

console.log("Final: "+ JSON.stringify(historic));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, instead of `.attr()` make use of `.data()` method of jQuery:

```
var historic = []; // array declaration

$('.tpl').each(function() { // iteration
    historic.push($(this).data('points')); // storing values in array
});

console.log(historic);
```

Comment: +1. Question, is there a specific advantage to use `data("x")` rather than  `attr("data-x")` ? (asside of saving 5 characters)

Comment: I think jquery has a `.data()` method for new `html5` specific attributes and  i think this is serving data for usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
var historic=[];
console.log("Initial: "+ JSON.stringify(historic));

$.each($('.tpl'), function(){
    historic.push($(this).data('points'));
});

console.log("Final: "+ JSON.stringify(historic));
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvPH/6/